# Flags are being declined, I can't figure it out why?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation, moderators, declined-flags

Recently I flagged two answers in Stack Overflow. Both got rejected, I read the explanation given by moderator, but I still not figure it out what's the issue with those flags.

## **Flag 1**

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639780/uitableview-with-static-cells-does-not-appear/8640025#8640025) answer, because it seems a comment to me.

[image: Flag 1]

And Moderator declined the flag, by saying that t

> here is no evidence to support it

Really ??? It's clearly understandable that, it's a question or comment. There is no explanation or links or images or even any code snippet.

[image: Reject 1]

## **Flag 2**

This is the second flagged [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309058/how-to-play-video-url-with-mpmovieplayer-in-ios-8-0/27309142#27309142)

[image: Flag 2]

I also believe it should be a comment, and even if it's taken as an answer it's very low quality.

The rejection reason was:

> No evidence to support it

Now, I'm thinking what is the evidence they are talking about ???

[image: Reject 2]

Can someone help me to sort it out ? So that I can improve my flags in future.

Comment: Just because an answer is short doesn't mean it *needs* to be a comment - especially if it answers the question.

Comment: @Mysticial: Can you read both questions too, before putting comment. In one thing the OP asked that the MPMovie player is not working in XCode 6, answer was use MPMovie player, is that makes any sense to you ? And another one was a question posted as answer, are you saying it's also an answer ?

Comment: The first one is a borderline case. If it was posted today, it would probably be deleted or converted to a comment. But in this case, it's old and it's gotten a lot of upvotes. That probably tipped the moderator's mind in favor of keeping it. In the second one, is actually an answer. OP asks how to do X, the answer says use Y class.

Comment: Those are both answers. Please read the official [when an answer is not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) post.

Comment: @Mysticial why are we applying different standards to answers today and from days of old? Just because someone posted a crap answer 3 years ago does not mean that it should be ignored and "don't use that as an example of how we should answer today - it has up votes, but don't do that now."  Inconsistent standards make it confusing for new users and people trying to take part in communit moderation.

Comment: @MichaelT Regardless, the standards have *never* been equal between today and old. Moderators (and normal users) are more hesitant to delete something that has a lot of upvotes and is clearly helpful to others. The very presence of the historical lock feature already implies special treatment for old posts.

Comment: @MichaelT: Because the standards evolve over time. The presence of a previous question on a topic does not mean that a new question on that topic is appropriate now, and the same applies to answers to previous questions. New questions and answers have to adhere to present guidelines, but to retroactively apply guidelines that did not exist at the time the question or answer were posted is not always appropriate (or even possible). Mods would spend 100% of their time dealing with historic questions and would have no time to deal with current issues.

Comment: @KenWhite which is why it is important for community moderation when possible. However, for community moderation to act upon an answer, that answer needs to be negatively scored to be deleted. This means either to clean up the site one of three things has to happen: meta effect from chat to get down votes, meta effect from meta to get  down votes, or a mod flag. Mods have said the meta effect is not something to be invoked and aren't acting upon flags where its too big to do simply. What is the process that we, the community, can act on to clean up poor answers in this case?

Answer (score 12):

Although both of those answers are on the short side, they're not bad enough to warrant migration to comment or outright deletion.

They each should be expanded to be a *good* answer (i.e., I wouldn't upvote them), but they are both still valid answers.

By the way, "it should be a comment" falls under "not an answer". Since custom reason flags bother the already overwhelmed diamond mods, it's better to use the NAA flag in cases such as this.